# Function 'delay' doesn't exist in GCC

Tags: c, function, gcc

I really can't understand what is wrong with my code. My teacher said to add `time.h` and `process.h` but still doesn't work. I am using `TDM-GCC-64`.
**Code**:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <time.h>
int main()
{
  char str[30];
  int i;
  printf("Enter the string: ");
  scanf("%s",str);
  for(i=0;str[i]!='\0';i++)
  {
    printf("%c",str[i]);
    delay(1000);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Institutions teaching their students a decades-out-of-date implementation of C or C++ (the Turbo products, `conio.h` is usually a dead giveaway) are really doing their students a disservice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `delay` function. You should use `sleep` instead.

So instead of

```
delay(1000);
```

do

```
 sleep(1); // sleep 1 second
```

Don't forget to include <unistd.h>

Comment: Thanks to you a lot! Actually my teacher uses Turbo C (i know it expired) but yeah thanks.

Comment: You might want to add a note that `sleep` is a POSIX (e.g. Linux or macOS) function. On Windows it's `Sleep`, which takes a number of milliseconds as argument.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude maybe writing the delay function was the actual homework task

Comment: @SteveWhoLikesLinux That might explain it. It's probably a TurboC-specific function (as is the `<process.h>` header file).

Comment: Some of the old TurboC versions had a `delay()`. They might not have had `sleep()`. This is a matter of finding out what the specific compiler offers, and how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the `delay` function you need to write it yourself. For example the blocking version:

```
void delay(unsigned milliseconds)
{
    clock_t pause;
    clock_t start;

    pause = milliseconds * (CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 1000);
    start = clock();
    while( (clock() - start) < pause );
}
```

Comment: Won't this generate a lot of CPU activity for no purpose?